# Qxcb connection on rosrun turtlesim

Tags: ros, rosnode, turtlesim, rosrun, turtlesim-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I am following the beginner rosnode tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingNodes
I have installed ros in bash. When I enter command "rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node" after running "roscore", I get the following error:

```
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display :0.0
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Are there any solutions to this?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262574/qxcb-connection-on-rosrun-turtlesim/) by [Isam Abdullah](https://answers.ros.org/users/25753/isam-abdullah/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-05-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kathrin@ros](https://answers.ros.org/users/35413/kathrin@ros/) on 2018-05-23**:
Hi,
I'm a beginner in Ros and just started the tutorial too.Moreover I'm working on SLAM methods with ROS. Maybe ur still interested in this topic and would like to discuss with me about it.

**Comment by [Isam Abdullah](https://answers.ros.org/users/25753/isam-abdullah/) on 2018-05-23**:
Yeah sure. I would be happy to help/discuss.

**Comment by [kathrin@ros](https://answers.ros.org/users/35413/kathrin@ros/) on 2018-05-23**:
I'm a total beginner. But did you manage this connection problem?

**Comment by [Isam Abdullah](https://answers.ros.org/users/25753/isam-abdullah/) on 2018-05-23**:
Are you installing ros in windows bash? If so, then it is not supported and you have to do alot of hacks to make it work on that.

**Comment by [Isam Abdullah](https://answers.ros.org/users/25753/isam-abdullah/) on 2018-05-23**:
So it is advisable for a beginner to work in ubuntu.

**Comment by [kathrin@ros](https://answers.ros.org/users/35413/kathrin@ros/) on 2018-05-23**:
Yes, I did. I managed it with Xserver, seems to be stable.It seems more complicated to me to change to ubuntu...

**Comment by [Isam Abdullah](https://answers.ros.org/users/25753/isam-abdullah/) on 2018-05-23**:
Great!... btw are you university/college graduate?

**Comment by [kathrin@ros](https://answers.ros.org/users/35413/kathrin@ros/) on 2018-05-23**:
Did you installed ubuntu additionally to windows?Does it work well parallel?

**Comment by [Isam Abdullah](https://answers.ros.org/users/25753/isam-abdullah/) on 2018-05-23**:
Yes... It works well to have dual boot. Windows and ubuntu side by side.

**Comment by [kathrin@ros](https://answers.ros.org/users/35413/kathrin@ros/) on 2018-05-23**:
I am an electroengineering student, trying to advance in my bachelor thesis(just began).And you?

**Comment by [Isam Abdullah](https://answers.ros.org/users/25753/isam-abdullah/) on 2018-05-23**:
Well, I have graduated from my BS computer science previous year. I have been working in a startup related to computer vision and deep learning since the past year.

**Comment by [kathrin@ros](https://answers.ros.org/users/35413/kathrin@ros/) on 2018-05-23**:
Sounds great. I've tried to run ubuntu on/as a live stick. But I didn't know how to access ros,not knowing where it is located on the hard disk or haven't set any path variable. How did you run ubuntu and how to get access to the ros without downloading it again?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I have installed ros in bash

do you mean Windows 10 / WSL with this? If so, then that is highly experimental and especially anything with a GUI will require (quite) some tweaks. Are you running a Windows X server fi?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-05-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Isam Abdullah](https://answers.ros.org/users/25753/isam-abdullah/) on 2017-05-26**:
Yes, I mean Windows 10/WSL. I don't know if I am running a Windows X server fi. Please help me on the tweaks..

**Comment by [Isam Abdullah](https://answers.ros.org/users/25753/isam-abdullah/) on 2017-05-26**:
Hi, thanks for the answer. I searched the windows X server thing, and I found the fix.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-26**:
Could you please mention your platform next time you post a question?

And also: please take into account that what you're doing (ROS on Win10/WSL) is completely unsupported.

If you are just starting out I'm not sure using such a platform would be something I'd recommend.

**Comment by [Isam Abdullah](https://answers.ros.org/users/25753/isam-abdullah/) on 2017-05-26**:
I would surely. Thanks

**Comment by [Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/31822/kumar/) on 2017-09-07**:
Can you please share the tweaks you did to make this run? Thanks in advance!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-08**:
I'm afraid I don't remember. The situation with ROS on WSL is rather different now as well as the main obstacles have been removed. See #q238646.

**Comment by [Cabajo](https://answers.ros.org/users/32498/cabajo/) on 2017-11-04**:
With a W10 PC, you need to install Xming to run GUI https://www.pcworld.com/article/3055403/windows/windows-10s-bash-shell-can-run-graphical-linux-applications-with-this-trick.html I managed to run at least Firefox, but I'm still having some challenge with "rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node"